# How to make a textbox that runs the vb.net line in it?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm new here and I already searched for answers but is it possible, if you typ in textbox1 "Application.ExitThread" it runs that or if you do "CheckBox1.Checked =  True" it does that too?? Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: searched in google: "*vb.net compile code at runtime*". Result among many others: http://www.aboutmydot.net/desktop-applications/compile-and-execute-code-at-runtime.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're looking for VBCodeProvider. So you can execute Code at runtime

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.vbcodeprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks you! Cause I'm trying to make a server and I want to remote control the GUI easily, it's working now, thanks!

Comment: Ow, but if I do CheckBox1.Checked = True it doesn't do that